# What are good KPI's for measuring high-level strategic goals?

Tags: strategy, kpi

I need to track organizational execution on high-level, long-term goals, along the lines of:

- Encourage collaboration
- Improve productivity
- Increase customer satisfaction

Some of these can be measured via surveys of empowerment, etc. But how can I create KPI measurements for tracking execution on strategic goals of this nature, which aren't easily measured?

Comment: What industry are you working in?

Comment: IT of financial sector company

Comment: Surely your HR unit has something on this to help you.

Comment: Taking a page from StackOverflow: "What have you tried?" Why is your project tracking these metrics, what do you want the metrics to tell you, and why are you finding them hard to measure? More context, please.

Comment: Hi Brad, welcome to PMSE! If you're not getting the answers you hoped for here, you can use this [edit] link to add more details to your post. This will bump it back to the top of the main page as well. Good luck! ;)

Answer (score 2):

For customer satisfaction, I encourage you to look at the [NetPromoter](http://www.netpromoter.com/) system.  It's simple, easy to implement.

For productivity, collaboration, etc., you might find some way to measure these things, but  your real strategy should be to measure your downstream goals.  Ask yourself: if your team doubled their productivity and doubled the collaboration that occurred, then what?  Perhaps your company's profits would increase, mistakes might be reduced, and/or they would meet their team objectives for the year.  You'll want to make sure you're tracking the big-picture metrics before you track the softer skills that drive those goals.

Comment: Using NPS is actually an interesting idea. We've used it externally in the past, but it might even work for measuring internal employee empowerment. Thx for the lead.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I won't measure *encourage collaboration, improve productivity, increase customer satisfaction* separately, because an organization may need the combination of those three. The individual KPI may provide a local view on the overall progress. For example, a high KPI on the productivity doesn't necessarily means that the organization is successful - the KPI for customer satisfaction may be low on the other hand.

I would start with something simple: **number of new customers, number of old customers**. The first will tell you how good is the organization's improvement plan, the second will tell you how reliable the service is. These KPIs are easy to measure and understand on each level of an organization.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with other answers that you need to track downstream goals and should possibly challenge the need to track productivity as a strategic goal. That said it can be a useful metric for comparison and understanding its contribution to bigger goals e.g. profit.

However, I understand that many companies set targets (either internally or externally) for things such as collaboration, productivity and customer satisfaction.

For you to track these, you should break them down into tangible deliverables.

For collaboration consider things such as implementing a collaboration or social networking application e.g. Confluence, Sharepoint, etc. Measure its usage and effectiveness e.g usage of the application increased by x% over x period and was an essential tool in delivering project x.

Research methods for measuring productivity because it can be complex but this is not a soft metric so you will be able to find methods for doing this. Measuring productivity is a measure of the efficiency of production. How you do this is dependent on the industry you work in and the work being carried out.

Customer satisfaction can be measured by surveys and by more in-depth techniques such as 1-1 interviews, focus groups and workshops.

I think the goals you want to track are relevant but only within the context that some of the other answers give i.e. What are you ultimately trying to measure? What bigger goals do the ones you've listed contribute to?